# How to include a nested resource that has a polymorphic association with ActiveRecordSerializer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers, netflix, fastjsonapi

## I'm using Netflix's [jsonapi-rails](https://github.com/jsonapi-rb/jsonapi-rails) gem to serialize my API. I need to build a `response.json` object that includes the associated comments for a post.

#### `Post` model:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :comments, as: :commentable
end
```

#### Polymorphic `Comment` model

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true
end
```

#### PostSerializer

```
class PostSerializer
  include FastJsonapi::ObjectSerializer
  attributes :body
  has_many :comments, serializer: CommentSerializer, polymorphic: true
end
```

#### CommentSerializer

```
class CommentSerializer
  include FastJsonapi::ObjectSerializer
  attributes :body, :id, :created_at
  belongs_to :post
end
```

## Posts#index

```
  class PostsController < ApplicationController
    def index
      @posts = Post.all
      hash = PostSerializer.new(@posts).serialized_json

      render json: hash
    end
  end
```

What I've got so far only gives me the comment type and id, but I **NEED** the comment's `body` as well.

[image]

Please help!

Thanks in advance~!

Answer (score 4):

Although [not very intuitive](https://github.com/Netflix/fast_jsonapi/issues/105) this behaviour is there by design. According to the JSON API **relationship data** and actual **related resource data** belong in different objects of the structure

You can read more here:

- [Fetching Relationships](http://jsonapi.org/format/#fetching-relationships)
- [Inclusion of Related Resources](http://jsonapi.org/format/#fetching-includes)

To include the body of the Comments your serializers would have to be:

```
class PostSerializer
  include FastJsonapi::ObjectSerializer
  attributes :body, :created_at
  has_many :comments
end

class CommentSerializer
  include FastJsonapi::ObjectSerializer
  attributes :body, :created_at
end
```

and your controller code:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @posts = Post.all
    options = {include: [:comments]}
    hash = PostSerializer.new(@posts, options).serialized_json

    render json: hash
  end
end
```

The response for a single Post would look something like this:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "attributes": {
        "body": "A test post!"
      },
      "id": "1",
      "relationships": {
        "comments": {
          "data": [
            {
              "id": "1",
              "type": "comment"
            },
            {
              "id": "2",
              "type": "comment"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "type": "post"
    }
  ],
  "included": [
    {
      "attributes": {
        "body": "This is a comment 1 body!",
        "created_at": "2018-05-06 22:41:53 UTC"
      },
      "id": "1",
      "type": "comment"
    },
    {
      "attributes": {
        "body": "This is a comment 2 body!",
        "created_at": "2018-05-06 22:41:59 UTC"
      },
      "id": "2",
      "type": "comment"
    }
  ]
}
```